# How to create a hash based on two attributes of objects in an array?

Tags: ruby, sum

Suppose I have the following class, `product.rb`:

```
require 'yaml'

class Product
    attr_accessor :id, :price

    def initialize args = {}
        options = {:id => "", :price => 0}.merge(args)
        self.id, self.price = options[:id], options[:price]
    end

    def inspect
        self.to_yaml        
    end
end
```

And the following example program, `example.rb`:

```
require_relative 'product'

products = Array.new

(1..5).each do |n| # Create 5 products with random id and price
    products << Product.new(
        :id => rand(1..5),
        :price => rand(10..50))
end

products.each { |p| puts p.inspect }
```

Example output from running `example.rb`:

```
C:\>ruby example.rb
--- !ruby/object:Product
id: 3
price: 48
--- !ruby/object:Product
id: 2
price: 47
--- !ruby/object:Product
id: 5
price: 32
--- !ruby/object:Product
id: 5
price: 49
--- !ruby/object:Product
id: 3
price: 33
```

The result is an array of objects of type Product, with duplicate ids.

How can I create a hash with id as the key and the sum of price as the value?

Example of desired result:

```
{ "2" => 47, "3" => 81, "5" => 81 } # { id => sum of price }
```

Comment: Is the hash supposed to be ordered by id?

Comment: Ordering by id is not necessary in this particular case, but it would be a nice bonus. I can always sort the resulting hash after it has been created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `each_with_object` to inject a Hash with default value of 0, like this:

`products.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |p, result| result[p.id] += p.price }`

Comment: Perfect, I wasn't aware of `each_with_object` and was fumbling around with `map` and lambdas. Ruby being Ruby, I knew there was probably an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

```
products = Array.new
sum_hash = Hash.new(0) # new hash with default 0 value

(1..5).each do |n| # Create 5 products with random id and price
  id = rand(1..5)
  price = rand(10..50)

  sum_hash[id] += price

  products << Product.new(
    :id => id,
    :price => price)
end

products.each { |p| puts p.inspect }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to use [group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) :

```
products.group_by(&:id)
        .map{|id, ps| [id, ps.map(&:price).inject(:+)] }
        .to_h
```